# Dropdown menus not showing properly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a nav for a website in html and css. It is very simple, and the only thing I want is to display dropdown menus and color them when hovered.

Right now I'm almost there, however I still have two problems:

1. The elements are overlapping
2. When you hover a submenu, there are two "hover" squared backgrounds
   displayed.

I have the following CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: rgb(147, 147, 147);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 8%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0.3em rgb(44, 171, 185) outset;
    box-shadow: 0 0.18em 0.625em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
header nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);

}

header nav ul li.active:hover {
    background-color: rgba(48, 67, 91, 0.64);
}

header nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: inherit;
}

header nav ul li:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: rgba(48, 67, 91, 0.35);
}

header nav ul li.dropdown ul {
    display: none;
}

header nav ul li.dropdown:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

}

header nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

And my html is the following:

```
<body>

<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Element1</a></li>
            <li><a href="element2/index.html">Element2</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="menu/index.html">Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#submenu1.html">Submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#submenu2.html">Submenu2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

</body>
```

What I want is to change the background of the hovered element and to display correctly the subelements in the dropdowns.

I hope I was clear enough, thank you

You can see the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/hdd260s4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I changed according to your requirement. Please use this code.let me know any query.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
header {
    background-color: rgb(147, 147, 147);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0.3em rgb(44, 171, 185) outset;
    box-shadow: 0 0.18em 0.625em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
header nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}

header nav li {
    float: left;
}
header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: inherit;
}
header nav li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

    text-decoration: none;
}
.active {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
header nav ul li.active:hover {
    background-color: rgba(48, 67, 91, 0.64);
}
header nav li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
     background-color: rgba(48, 67, 91, 0.35);
}

header nav li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
     background-color: rgba(48, 67, 91, 0.35);
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Element1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Element2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Menu</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Submenu1</a>
      <a href="#">Submenu2</a>
      <a href="#">Submenu3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

</header>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

I uploaded My code here please see this demo.https://jsfiddle.net/hansraj/bmbuLcfk/

Comment: Pleasure is mine:)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and change according to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Hide Dropdown Using CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown{
        min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown li{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I uploaded My code here please see this demo.https://jsfiddle.net/hansraj/z2sojhbm/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already made some changes based on your code, however I'm not yet there, but closer. May you give it a look and help me find the problem? It's all working but is missing the hover color in the items of the dropdowns and the submenu is displayed above the menu, not under it. This is my link: https://jsfiddle.net/wu6ghhrn/